# Replace a FOR loop aimed at multiplying df['value'] by param['factor'] when the combinations of 'param' and 'df1' corresponding variables match

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, apply

I am trying to replace a FOR loop by any other way that would fit, for performence reason.

The FOR loop aimed at multiplying df1['value'] by param['factor'] in a new column df1['new_vallue'] when the combinations of param[ 'table'], param[ 'y'], param[ 'x'],param[ 't'] match df1[ 'table'], df1[ 'y'], df1[ 'x'],df1[ 't']?

The first code snippet is with the FOR loop and gives the expected results.

When 'df1' contains 5 million rows and 'param' 1000, it takes 30 min to run. Perhaps with a dictionnary, or a mapping?

The second code snippet is with the 'apply' function.
Serge Ballesta explained why the snippet below with the 'Apply' does not work, thanks to him.

```
  import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame( {

   'date': ['31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019'],
   'id': ['X1','X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2','X1','X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2'],
   'table': ['TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2','TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2','TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2','TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2'],
   'y': [300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310],
   'x': [10,20,10,10,20,20,10,10,20,20,40,40,40,10,10,10],
   't': ['o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o'],
   'value': [0.37,0.98,3,45,0.76,12,14,31,51,1.7,12,14,12,19,123,43]
    } );

param = pd.DataFrame( {
   'table': ['TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2'],
   'y': [300,310,300,310],
   'x': [10,20,30,10],
   't': ['o','o','o','o'],
   'factor': [12,34,22,43]
    } );


df1['new_value'] = 0


def CALC(df, table, y, x, t, factor):
    df.loc[(df['table'] == table ) & 
            (df['y']== y) 
            & (df['x']== x ) & (df['t']== t),['new_value']] = df['value']*factor

param_l = param.values.tolist()

for row in param_l[0:]:           
    table = row[2]
    y = row[4]
    x = row[3]
    t = row[1]
    factor = row[0]
    CALC(df1,table,y,x,t,factor)

# second snippet: with the apply

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame( {
   'date': ['31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2018','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019','31/12/2019'],
   'id': ['X1','X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2','X1','X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2'],
   'table': ['TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2','TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2','TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2','TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2'],
   'y': [300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310,300,310],
   'x': [10,20,10,10,20,20,10,10,20,20,40,40,40,10,10,10],
   't': ['o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o'],
   'value': [0.37,0.98,3,45,0.76,12,14,31,51,1.7,12,14,12,19,123,43]
    } );

param = pd.DataFrame( {
   'table': ['TABLE1','TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE2'],
   'y': [300,310,300,310],
   'x': [10,20,30,10],
   't': ['o','o','o','o'],
   'factor': [12,34,22,43]
    } );


df1['new_value'] = 0


def CALC(df, table, y, x, t, factor):
    df.loc[(df['table'] == table ) & 
            (df['y']== y) 
            & (df['x']== x ) & (df['t']== t),['new_value']] = df['value']*factor
    return(df)

df1['new_value'] = param.apply(lambda row: CALC(df1,param['table'],param['y'],param['x'],param['t'],param['factor']))
```

Comment: The error is probably caused by df1 and param being unrelated. Anyway, you apply a function of row that never uses row. It is at least weird.

Comment: Thanks Serge Ballesta for taking the time to answer. What do you mean by 'unrelated'? The snippet with the FOR loop leads the expected result, did you run the snippet?. I am just trying to replicate the FOR loop with an apply because the FOR loop takes ages with df1 wit hmillions rows and param with > 1000 rows. Then, what do you mean by 'you apply a function of row that never uses row. It is at least weird.' Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, it looks like you had not understood what `apply` does!

First, to apply a function on every row of a dataframe, you must use `axis=1` as parameter, because by default `apply` uses columns.

Then (with `axis=1`), the function is applied on each row and the return value is used to build the Series or DataFrame that the `apply` will return. So when CALC returns `df1`,

```
df1['new_value'] = param.apply(lambda row: CALC(df1,row['table'],row['y'],row['x'],
                                                row['t'],row['factor']), axis=1)
```

will write in each row of the `new_value` column a reference to `df1`! Any attempt to just print df1 will result in a StackOverflow error because of the circular reference...

As calc modifies `df1['new_value']` you must not assign it that way but to a dummy variable:

```
_ = param.apply(lambda row: CALC(df1,row['table'],row['y'],row['x'], row['t'],row['factor']),
                axis=1)
```

---

Above apply call gives the expected result, but is not more efficient than the first snippet. In fact the idiomatic way is to use a `merge`:

```
df1['new_value'] = df1['value'] * df1.merge(
    param, on=['table', 'y', 'x', 't'], how='left')['factor'].fillna(0.)
```

No external loop is involved here. With timeit, it is 3 times faster for a 15 rows dataframe, and the benefit is probably higher for bigger ones. This should not be a surprise, because apply generaly involves loops at the Python level. Here are some references:

- [A Beginner’s Guide to Optimizing Pandas Code for Speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)
- [How Not to Use pandas' "apply"](https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/)

Comment: Thank you indeed for the explanation....I understand better how 'apply' works. So, I do not see how 'apply' can be used to replicate what the FOR loop is doing in the snippet. Do you have any idea about how I can improve the perfomance of this FOR loop aimed at multiplying df1['value'] by param['factor'] in a new column df1['new_vallue'] when the combinations of param[ 'table'], param[ 'y'], param[ 'x'],param[ 't'] match df1[ 'table'], df1[ 'y'], df1[ 'x'],df1[ 't']? When 'df1' contains 5 million rows and 'param' 1000, it takes 30 min to run. Perhaps with a dictionnary, or a mapping?

Comment: @Spawn77: See my edit for a much better way and some references on Pandas optimization and `apply`.

Comment: It is indeed A LOT faster: 5 sec vs. 30 min on a 5 mln rows 'DF1' and 1000 rows 'param'.  As I am self learning python, I was naively expecting kind of a fancy way to do it, but actually a good old left join make perfectly the work...Thanks a lot for this Serge Ballesta. In fact I am frustrated as I am using join since ages and didn't realised that it could make the deal! I am definitely a poor programmer. PS: I had to reset the index of my input dataframe to make the left join work... I tried it by intuittion and it works, I do not know why